# make cumulative sum of month using sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

i have a data like this in my table:

```
> HourWork  MonthName
> 
> 366.00    May 2010    
> 1000.00   Sep 2010    
> 1704.00   Oct 2010    
> 3000.00   Nov 2010
```

now, i want to make a stored procedure to get the result of this:

```
> HourWork  MonthName
> 
> 366.00    May 2010    
> 1366.00   Sep 2010    
> 2704.00   Oct 2010    
> 4704.00   Nov 2010
```

means get the value of next month and so some with current month data.

any one give me a way how can i get the result like this using stored procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE WorkTimeLog
(
    WTLID       int identity    NOT NULL,
    HourWork    numeric(7,2)    NOT NULL,
    MonthStart  datetime        NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(WTLID)
)
go

set dateformat dmy;

insert WorkTimeLog values (366.00,  '01-May-2010')
insert WorkTimeLog values (1000.00, '01-Sep-2010')
insert WorkTimeLog values (1704.00, '01-Oct-2010')
insert WorkTimeLog values (3000.00, '01-Nov-2010');
go

select  IsNull((select HourWork from WorkTimeLog where MonthStart = wtl.MonthStart) + (select HourWork from WorkTimeLog where MonthStart = (select MAX(MonthStart) from WorkTimeLog where MonthStart < wtl.MonthStart)), wtl.HourWork) as PairTotal,
        RIGHT(CONVERT(char(11), wtl.MonthStart, 13), 8) as Period
from    WorkTimeLog as wtl 
order   by wtl.MonthStart
go
```

---

```
PairTotal   Period
366.00     May 2010
1366.00   Sep 2010
2704.00   Oct 2010
4704.00   Nov 2010
```